# ASP.NET Core middleware return image

Tags: response, middleware

I have a asp.net core middleware that should log some request stuff and then return an image.

Within the middleware response I like to return an image as a byte[]. I played around with the context.Reponse.WriteAsync() object but did not find any solution to return an image.

```
  public class TrackerMiddleware
    {
        private readonly IClientInformationManager _clientInformationManager;
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public TrackerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IClientInformationManager clientInformationManager)
        {
            _next = next;
            _clientInformationManager = clientInformationManager;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            var clientInfo = new ClientInformationLogDTO();
            clientInfo.AgentContext = context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"];

          
            await _clientInformationManager.CreateLogAsync(clientInfo);

            //TODO: Return image here
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("");

            //await _next(context);
        }
    }
```

How can I modify my middleware to return an image?

Answer (score 1):

```
await context.Response.BodyWriter.WriteAsync(new byte[]{ 1 });
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.